# How to parse and distinguish different and varying arguments of a user command with a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, capturing-group

I'm trying to interpret user commands as dash optional flag.

```
{run -o -f -a file1 file2}
```

Something like this:

```
/{run (-o|-f) (\w+) (.+?)}/g;
```

Is very limiting with only 1 choice of flag.

I'm looking for a regex that can properly parse the string with any amount of dash flags, spit out the flags into groups, and not worry about a set amount of whitespace in between.

```
string = "{run    -a  file1 file2}"
string = "{run    -a -o -f  file1 file2}"
string = "{run -f-a-o  file1 file2}"
```

`string.match(regex)` should output each flag and each file name.

Example output would be:

```
["f", "a", "o", "file1", "file2"]
```

Or if not possible, something like this:?

```
["-f-a-o", "file1", "file2"]
```

Comment: In what way is this question unfocused? Literally a simple single regex question.

Comment: A single regex is not capable of ... *"parse[ing] the string with any amount of dash flags, spit out the flags into groups"*. The task as described will always need the combination of a regex and an additional (most probably) map and/or reduce task.

Comment: @PeterSeliger oh really I didn't realize. What about my revised output, is that possible?

Comment: You could just match the parts you want, provided you don't also want to check validity of the command as a whole. Something like /\b(?:\w\b|(?!run)(?!-)[^{}\s]+)/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single regex is capable of capturing a maximum amount of 9 groups.

Thus ... *"parse[ing a] string with any amount of dash flags"* ... like the OP does demand can not be achieved by a single regex alone.

A good enough approach was to [capture](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) both groups, the [`flags` sequence and the `files` sequence](https://regex101.com/r/VFjeK1/1) and then to process them into a concatenated list of separated **flag** and **file name** items ...

```js
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/VFjeK1/1]
const regXFlagsAndFiles =
  (/^\{\s*run(?:\s+-(?<flags>[a-z]+(?:\s*-[a-z]+)*))*\s+(?<files>[\w.]+(?:\s+[\w.]+)*)\s*\}$/);
  
function parseFlagAndFileList(value) {
  const {
    flags,
    files,
  } = regXFlagsAndFiles
    .exec(String(value))
    ?.groups || {};

  return (flags
    ?.split(/\s*-\s*/)
    ?? []
  ).concat(
    files
      ?.split(/\s+/)
      ?? []
  );
}

console.log([

  '{run file1 file2}',
  '{run    -a  file1 file2}',
  '{run    -a -o -f  file1 file2}',
  '{run -f-a-o  file1 file2}',

].map(parseFlagAndFileList));

console.log([

  '{run}',
  '{run      }',
  '{run file1  }',
  '{run    -abc  file1.foo file2.bar  }',
  '{run    -ab -ogg -fgg  file1.baz file2  }',
  '{run -f-a-ob  file1 file2.biz  }',
  '{ run -a -b       }',
  '{ fun -a -b       }',

].map(parseFlagAndFileList));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A regex which almost covers the OP's wish of doing it all with just one simple pattern would look like this one ... [`/[\w.]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/VFjeK1/3).

It of cause ...

- covers no validation at all,
- and needs to be supported by ...

  - [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and
  - [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/VFjeK1/3]
const regXCommandTokens = (/[\w.]+/g);

console.log([

  '{run file1 file2}',
  '{run    -a  file1 file2}',
  '{run    -a -o -f  file1 file2}',
  '{run -f-a-o  file1 file2}',

].map(command => command.match(regXCommandTokens).slice(1)));

console.log([

  '{run}',
  '{run      }',
  '{run file1  }',
  '{run    -abc  file1.foo file2.bar  }',
  '{run    -ab -ogg -fgg  file1.baz file2  }',
  '{run -f-a-ob  file1 file2.biz  }',
  '{ run -a -b       }',
  '{ fun -a -b       }',

].map(command => command.match(regXCommandTokens).slice(1)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```